# Call Maps for directions from a webpage with iOS6

Tags: url, navigation, ios6, ios6-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Current Location doesn't work with Apple Maps IOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539009/current-location-doesnt-work-with-apple-maps-ios-6)

*Preamble:*

Given that:

if you create a link like:

"http://maps.apple.com/maps?saddr=here&daddr="+theUrlEncodedDestinationAddress

it will open the native map app with a "static" route from where you are to the given destination, but gives you no way to start the live turn-by-turn navigation to the destination.

If you create a link like:

"http://maps.apple.com/maps?q="+theUrlEncodedDestinationAddress

it will open the native map app with a marker on the destination and from there with a few taps you can start the live navigation.

*Actual question:*

Is there a URL syntax to open the native map app AND just **start the live turn-by-turn navigation** to the destination with no questions asked?

I searched the Apple docs for this and couldn't find anything useful.

NOTE: I know that starting the navigation can be done from within a native app, but I'm not interested in that. I would like to start it with a URL from a simple web page.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry guys, this is not a duplicate. It's a different question. I'm asking how (if possible) to open the native app to show the live turn-by-turn directions to the desired destination.